# Is it possible to add 2 object inside adapter?

Tags: android, object, adapter

Is it possible to add 2 object class inside adapter like this?

```
public Adapter(Context context, List<ObjectItem> objectItem, List<ObjectItem2> objectItem2) {

}
```

this is example code: I've to parse json with nested json array, so the first json like:

```
dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);            
    ObjectItem item = new ObjectItem();
    item.setUserid(userid);
    item.setProfilePic(profile_photo);
    item.setName(profile_name);

    int jKomen = c.getJSONArray("comment_note").length();
    if(c.getJSONArray("comment_note").length() > 0) {
         commentNoteJsonArr = c.getJSONArray("comment_note");
         for (int j = 0; j < commentNoteJsonArr.length(); j++) {
               JSONObject d = commentNoteJsonArr.getJSONObject(j);
               String pName2 = d.isNull("profile_name") ? null : d.getString("profile_name");
               item.setName2(pName2);
               String pComment2 = d.isNull("content_comment") ? null : d.getString("content_comment");
               item.setComment2(pComment2);
         }
}
item.setLevel(Level.LEVEL_ONE);
Items.add(item);
}
```

And this is a second code after parse a json code in above:

```
dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

     ObjectItem2 item2 = new ObjectItem2();
     item2.setId(c.getString("id_note"));
     int jKomen = c.getJSONArray("comment_note").length();
     if(c.getJSONArray("comment_note").length() > 0) {
          commentNoteJsonArr = c.getJSONArray("comment_note");
          for (int j = 0; j < commentNoteJsonArr.length(); j++) {
               JSONObject d = commentNoteJsonArr.getJSONObject(j);

               item2.setUserid(d.getString("userid"));
               item2.setProfilePic(d.getString("profile_photo"));
               item2.setName(d.getString("profile_name"));
          }
}
item2.setLevel(Level.LEVEL_TWO);
Items2.add(item2);
}
```

Adapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So, I wanna add object Items and Items2 to adapter. so what should i do to clear it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using custom Adapter? Add some code also, to show that you did something\.

Comment: make them inherit from the same base class and use only one dataset.

Comment: please add some more code so we can help you

Comment: create an empty interface and make other class implementing it. now create a object array of your empty interface and pass in this any of the class object implemented by your empty interface. and in adapter check for instance in particular position.

Comment: ive edited my code, pls check it, thaanks

Comment: @PankajKumar yes im using custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create interface

```
public interface DispayItem {

}
```

now create classes implemeting that DispayItem interface

```
public class Class1 implements DispayItem {
    private int id;
    private String label;

    private Class1 () {
    }

    public static Class1 create( int id, String label ) {
        Class1 section = new Class1 ();
        section.setLabel(label);
        return section;
    }
}
```

class2

```
public class Class2 implements DispayItem {
    private int id;
    private String label;

    private Class2 () {
    }

    public static Class2 create( int id, String label ) {
        Class2 section = new Class2 ();
        section.setLabel(label);
        return section;
    }
}
```

to add items you can use it as

```
 DisplayItem[] displayItem= new DisplayItem[] {
                Class1.create( 100, "Class1"),
                Class2.create(101,"Class2"),
             };
```

in Your adapter

```
 public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, DisplayItem[] objects ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

using getView int adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

DisplayItem displayItem= this.getItem(position);

```
if(displayItem instanceof Class1){
//do work for class 1
 view = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem );
}
else if(displayItem instanceof Class2){
//do work for class 2
 view = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem );}

}
return view;}
```

Comment: Thank.. it works! :D

Comment: you can inflate different view based on that . further if you need let me know.